# SQL Foreign Key (Cannot add or update a child row)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

I have a relationship with tables (technical and problems) in the table have 3 states (in, waiting, out) in which the technical from the other table is selected.

[Relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FYHk.png)

the problem is that when I try to change the ID of a technician gives me the following error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`demo_stack`.`problem`, CONSTRAINT `problem_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`technical_id_in`) REFERENCES `technical` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Update:

```
UPDATE `technical` SET `id` = '14' WHERE `technical`.`id` = 1
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE technical (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE problem (
    id INT, 
    name varchar(255),
    technical_id_in INT,
    technical_id_waiting INT,
    technical_id_out INT,
    INDEX (technical_id_in,technical_id_waiting,technical_id_out),
    FOREIGN KEY (technical_id_in) REFERENCES technical(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (technical_id_waiting) REFERENCES technical(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (technical_id_out) REFERENCES technical(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO `technical` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('1', 'victor'), ('2', 'eduardo'), ('3', 'jose');

INSERT INTO `problem` (`id`, `name`, `technical_id_in`, `technical_id_waiting`, `technical_id_out`) VALUES ('1', 'Problem 1', '1', '2', '1'), ('2', 'Problem 2', '1', '1', '1');
```

anyone have any idea? Thanks !!!

Comment: Why do you try to renumber the rows? You get that error because you have row in problem referencing `technical`.`id` = 14.

Comment: yes, I want that when the ID of technical change, the other tables change too the ID...

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of the [MySql reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
UPDATE technical SET id = 14 WHERE ID = 1;
UPDATE problem SET technical_id_in = 14 WHERE technical_id_in = 1;
UPDATE problem SET technical_id_waiting = 14 WHERE technical_id_waiting = 1;
UPDATE problem SET technical_id_out = 14 WHERE technical_id_out = 1;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
-- or "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION" if anything fails
```

You have to update all the foreign keys by yourself.

Also make sure, that you run this script within a transaction, and that you rollback the transaction if it anything fails.